# Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use Redis CentOS access remotely

Tags: redis, centos

I've set up Redis on a CentOS 8 Stream virtual machine on an ipv4 address. I've installed it, and configured it, but I cannot access it remotely, I've set:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

I used to have it set to this...

```
bind 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0
```

However this meant that restarting redis would fail.

Now, whenever I check if Redis is running using the systemctl command, it's running, but when running `redis-server` within the box I get:

> Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use

And I cannot access it remotely with:

```
redis-cli -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -a mypass
```

What am I missing?

I just keep getting:

> Could not connect to Redis at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:6379: Connection refused